# Two question marks and two ampersand in query string?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

Ech, my query string look's like:

```
http://localhost/index.php?page=public&another=http://www.google.com?omg=tt&nop=asd
```

And afcourse i rewrite it with regex to:
regex: 
`RewriteRule ^pass-([^=]*)=([^=]*)$ index.php?page=$1&another=$2 [L]`

```
http://localhost/pass-url=http://www.google.com?omg=tt&nop=asd
```

(1)But then url becomes to: http://www.google.com only.

If i try **urlencode** with this url without regex:

```
http://localhost/index.php?page=public&another=http://www.google.com?omg=tt&nop=asd
```

it echo:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%3Fomg%3Dtt
```

(2)In this case `&nop=asd` part gone.

So how to make (1) work and why (2) do this ?
The biggest question would be how to pass two question and ampersand in query string ?
Any suggestion regarding this situation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your rewrite rule. Have it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^pass-([^=]*)=([^=]*)$ hw.php?page=$1&another=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Note that additional QSA flag which will make sure to preserve original query parameters.

Comment: Well, after 10 minutes realized that in php exist this:
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], so it gives even the /pass-url=, but with str_replace i "delete it" and url works. Anyways, thanks for your help.